# Good solution for Dynamic DNS

Tags: dns

I am looking for a good solution for Dynamic DNS for Android?
(Mostly for within LAN's).

I think an app should be easy to find, but one also needs a service.
(I could pay a little bit)

Answer (score 2):

The very-originally-named [Dynamic DNS Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.l6n.dyndns) is a fairly popular app for this purpose.

As for service, [noip](http://www.noip.com/) is popular, free, and reliable in my experience.